# Can someone help me derive this equation using Euler's formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant, eulers-method

$e^{a + bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$ -- Euler's formula

Euler's formula gives rise to $e^{πi} + 1 = 0$ -- Equation

Five important numbers of $0, 1,\pi , e$, and $i$ are in this equation.

How can this equation be derived from using Euler's formula?

Comment: $a=0$, $b=\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Substitute $a+ib=0+\pi i$:
$$
e^{0+\pi i }=e^0(\cos \pi+i\sin\pi)
$$